# In a WPF control that acts as a container, how do I place the content?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a WPF control that is meant to be a container in the same way `Border` and `ScrollViewer` are containers. It is called `EllipsisButtonControl`, and it is supposed to place an ellipsis button to the right of its content. Here's an example of how I intend for it to be used:

```
<local:EllipsisButtonControl>
    <TextBlock Text="Testing" />
</local:EllipsisButtonControl>
```

Here is the XAML for `EllipsisButtonControl`:

```
<ContentControl
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.EllipsisButtonControl"
    x:Name="ContentControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ElementName=ContentControl, Path=Content}" />

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding  ElementName=ContentControl, Path=Command}" Margin="3,0" Width="30" Height="24" MaxHeight="24" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="..." />

    </Grid>

</ContentControl>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class EllipsisButtonControl
    {
        public EllipsisButtonControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static string GetCommand(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                name: "Command",
                propertyType: typeof(ICommand),
                ownerType: typeof(EllipsisButtonControl),
                defaultMetadata: new UIPropertyMetadata());
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. It crashes the Designer with a `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException`.

I believe the binding on the `ContentPresenter` of the `EllipsisButtonControl` XAML is wrong, but I don't know how to make it right. What is the appropriate syntax to make that line reference the control's content? (e.g. The `TextBlock` defined in the usage example)

**Edit:**

poke provided a comprehensive answer below (including working code), but for the benefit of others who might share my initial misunderstanding, let me summarize the key concept here: A container control cannot "place content", per se. It achieves the desired effect by defining a template that modifies the way the calling XAML presents the content. The rest of the solution follows from that premise.

Comment: Why is Command an attached property, and not a regular dependency property?

Comment: Um... because the examples I was copying did it that way... Prompted by your question, I researched attached properties and learned that I should be using DependencyProperty.Register(), not DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(), on Line 23. Thanks.

Comment: *“A container control cannot "place content", per se.”* – It can, but there is only one content, so setting the content on the outside replaces the one inside. What you want is a “framing” where the content is placed inside (= a template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<local:EllipsisButtonControl>
    <TextBlock Text="Testing" />
</local:EllipsisButtonControl>
```

This does set the `Content` of your user control. But so does the following in the user control’s XAML:

```
<ContentControl …>
    <Grid>
        …
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

The calling XAML has precendence here, so whatever you do inside that user control’s XAML is actually ignored.

The solution here is to set the *template* of the user control. The template, in this case the control’s control template, determines how the control itself is rendered. The simplest template for a user control (and also its default) is just using a `ContentPresenter` there, but of course, you want to add some stuff around that, so we have to overwrite the template. This generally looks like this:

```
<ContentControl …>
    <!-- We are setting the `Template` property -->
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <!-- The template value is of type `ControlTemplate` and we should
             also set the target type properly so binding paths can be resolved -->
        <ControlTemplate>

            <!-- This is where your control code actually goes -->

        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Now this is the frame you need to make this work. However, once you’re inside the control template, you need to use the proper binding type. Since we are writing a template and want to bind to properties of the parent control, we need to specify the parent control as the relative source in bindings. But the easiest way to do that is to just use the [`TemplateBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) markup extension. Using that, a `ContentPresenter` can be placed like this inside the `ControlTemplate` above:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

And that should be all you need here in order to get the content presenter working.

However, now that you use a control template, of course you need to adjust your other bindings too. In particular the binding to your custom dependency property `Command`. This would generally look just the same as the template binding to `Content` but since our control template is targetting the type `ContentControl` and a `ContentControl` does not have your custom property, we need to explicitly reference your custom dependency property here:

```
<Button Command="{TemplateBinding local:EllipsisButtonControl.Command}" … />
```

Once we have that, all the bindings should work fine. (In case you are wondering now: Yes, the binding always targets the static dependency property on the type)

---

So, to sum this all up, your custom content control should look something like this:

```
<ContentControl
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.EllipsisButtonControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">

            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="…"
                        Command="{TemplateBinding local:EllipsisButtonControl.Command}" />
            </Grid>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: This approach requires a different way of thinking, but I'm starting to understand it. It raises two questions, though: 1) In order to make the code work, I had to change ContentControl to UserControl; why doesn't ContentControl work? 2) Could I have used a template binding to support the button's Command, rather than coding it as a dependency property?

Comment: As my understanding grows, I realize you've already answered Question 2: No, I could not have forgone the dependency property code for Command because ContentControl doesn't have a Command property (and after switching to UserControl, it doesn't either).

Comment: WPF in general requires you to rethink a bit how components work. In general, a control is just code with some template attached to it (see also “lookless components”); in many cases, there is a default template you want to overwrite. To answer your questions: 1) This also works with a `ContentControl`; you can see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/poke/bd9bcb6d1f1bf50b988ea8909edb99af) for a working example. 2) You can bind to other things inside the control template but here you want to expose a property on your `EllipsisButtonControl`, so you actually need a dependency property for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ElementName=ContentControl, Path=Content}" />
```

With this

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content={Binding Content} />
```

In your existing code you are making this `ContentPresenter` display the generated content of `EllipsesButtonControl`, which includes the `ContentPresenter` which must render the generated content of `ElipsesButtonControl` which includes the `ContentPresenter`..... Unlimited recursion.

Comment: Andrew, that solved the Designer crash problem, but something is still wrong. When I try the usage example, I see only the TextBlock as if it were not wrapped in the EllipsisButtonControl at all.

Answer (score 1):

The XAML of your EllipsisButtonControl already sets its Content to the top-level Grid. What you probably wanted is to create a `ControlTemplate`, e.g. like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.EllipsisButtonControl"
                x:Name="ContentControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=ContentControl, Path=Content}"/>

                <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=ContentControl, Path=Command}"
                    Margin="3,0" Width="30" Height="24" MaxHeight="24"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="..." />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```